# why can't create new app in react native

Tags: windows, installation, react-native

I'm beginner in react-native and I doing steps in a website of react-native 
and the app is working right,

but after doing some update

```
npm i react@latest --save
npm i react-native@latest --save
react-native upgrade
```

after that, I can't create any project by

```
react-native init projectName
```

I get this error 
[image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZah1.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually a problem on Windows with the latest version of react native (0.56)

[GitHub Issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/19654)

Try using version 0.55.4 by typing `react-native init --version="0.55.4" projectName`

Answer (score 0):

Not every version of react-native is compatible with every version of react. In the screenshot you sent, it says you need react@16.4.1 for react-native@0.56.0. Try doing `npm i react@16.4.1 --save` and then try `react-native init projectName` again.